# How to make php get last row from a Colum from mysql and make the result a variable that I can take with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables

I want php to get the last row of a specific Colum. Then I want the result to be a variable that javascript can take and have it a javascript variable.

something like this maybe

```
var result = [php variable]
```

My question is not just about how to make a php variable into javascript varibale but also on how to make php get the last row of a colum. Thanks, BTW (I'm new to this stuff so please be clear in your explainations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to *get the last row of a specific colum*, you need to query your database in a way such that your desired "last row colum value" is easily obtainable by php. This is commonly done using the SQL `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.

For example:

```sql
SELECT name FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This query's result-set will contain only the `name` column value for the `my_table` record with the highest `id`.

PHP can then assume that this data is contained by the first row in the result-set. For example (using `PDOStatement`):

```php
<?php
//...
$data = $pdoStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $data['name']; // The name column value of the row with the highest id
```

The specifics of the query for your use case are not made clear by your original post, but the above example logic should apply anyhow. Make sure you provide the appropriate query and have PHP fetch the first record in the result-set.

You can then parse this data into Javascript variables:

```php
<?php
<script>
    var result = "<?php echo $data['name']; ?>";
</script>
```

**Warning: This example is very basic, make sure you protect yourself against [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerabilities. Do not let database data provided by PHP be evaluated by Javascript without protection.**